# How can be numpy array C_CONTIGUOUS as well as F_CONTIGUOUS

Tags: numpy, memory-alignment

I thought I understand the concept of row-major (C_CONTIGUOUS) and column-major (F_CONTIGUOUS) memory alignment of numpy arrays. I thought that those two flags are mutually exclusive. But then I saw an array where both these flags were set to True.

In particular I tried the following commands:

```
b = np.arange(8,dtype='int8')
b.reshape(2,4,order='F')
b.flags
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

I would expect that after command b.reshape(2,4,order='F'), the array will  have F_CONTIGUOUS set to True and C_CONTIGUOUS set to False.

Can someone please explain me what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: `b.reshape(2,4,order='F')` does not operate in place.  Try `c = b.reshape(2,4,order='F')` and check `c.flags`.

Comment: A 1d array is both.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on? Less than you think. [`ndarry.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) is not an in-place operation. Thus this:

```
b = np.arange(8,dtype='int8')
b.reshape(2,4,order='F')
print(b.shape)
```

gives this as output:

```
(8,)
```

In other words, `b` is still 1D, and so can have both orders. Saving the result of `reshape` to a new array gives the result that you expected:

```
b = np.arange(8,dtype='int8')
c= b.reshape(2,4,order='F')
print(c.flags)
```

Output:

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Comment: It seems that numpy array with a shape of `(n,)` to `(1,1,1,1,1,1,..,n)` can always have both `C_CONTIGUOUS` and `F_CONTIGUOUS` being `True`. This means numpy treats an array as fixed length and simplify the location when it comes to indexing schema .